# Arduino's string.toDouble() not working

Tags: arduino, teensy

I am trying to convert a string to a double in one of my Arduino projects (specifically using a Teensy 3.5 in the Arduino IDE) using Arduino's [`string.toDouble()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringToDouble) command. When I try to implement the function as shown in the code below, I get the error:

```
<'class String' has no member named 'toDouble'>.
```

However, `string.toFloat()` and `string.toInt()` work successfully.

Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

```cpp
String myNumberString = "100";
double myNumber = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  
}

void loop() {
  myNumber = myNumberString.toDouble()+1;
  Serial.println(myNumber);
  myNumberString = String(myNumber);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that arduino declares `myNumberString` as a String Object, so you can't use `toDouble()` to convert the string into a double because the function is not defined in the String class. You will have to use `toFloat` to convert your string. Here's [the link](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) I used to find this.

Answer (score 1):

Seem like the Teensy's Arduino core is missing that function.

I only see `toInt` and `toFloat` [inside Teensy's implementation of the `String` class](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/cores/blob/1.35/teensy3/WString.cpp#L724-L734). While [the original Arduino core](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.8.5/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/WString.cpp#L746-L750) has it implemented.

Maybe you can use `atof` directly, like:

```cpp
myNumber = atof(myNumberString.c_str());
```